# Installer can't read the MSI file from Windows Installer folder

Tags: windows-installer, msp

I have an MSP (Microsoft Patch) file, which installs some updates. But when I run it, it shows an error message, which says, that it can't read the file from C:\Windows\Installer\SomeFileName.msi.

But this file is there, I checked that out. I tried to run it with Admin rights, from powered cmd, from PowerShell, no luck.

How I can fix that situation? Help please.

Comment: Try downloading the msp from its source again.  It might have been corrupted during download or copying.

Comment: That doesn't help. Sorry. I downloaded it several times, from several sources. Even its previous patch also in MSP format had the same error message.

Comment: See if this Microsoft Fixit can help..http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall

Comment: I tried it, it didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the cause of my problem. As it seems, these programs, which use MSPs should be installed in their default folder, such as "C:\Program Files...". Then these MSP patches work fine.